# PhpStorm 10 strange database query execution warning

Tags: database, phpstorm, sap-iq

I started using PhpStorm 10 and I faced strange database query behaviour (Sybase IQ), namely I'm getting error:

> [010P6] 010P6: A row was received and ignored. java.io.IOException: JZ0EM: End of data.

But query executes and I'm getting relevant result.

> **010P6 - A row was received and ignored.**
>   **Description**: An unexpected object of type 0xD1 was encountered in the result set being processed and was ignored. **Action**: Check the query that generated the result set and correct as required.

Can somebody explain what should I correct? The only guess I have is that it comes long char data in the output.

Comment: How does your query look like in the end? I guess, this will be the smoking gun.

Comment: @frlan My query is simple `select * `. I guess that it causes by table definition and content as it contains a long text data

Comment: I faced the same error but on Intellij IDEA. I've found out that the error occurs when select query returns more rows than set up in 'Result set page size' in IDEA settings (by default it's 500). IDEA uses here traditional approach to determine if we have next page: get N+1 record (by default 501), show 500 and ignore 501st, but if it exists then show 'Next' arrow to the next page.
The only thing that I don't know how to get rid of that error message from sybase driver.